# Can we render Angular components inside of our SVG templates?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

Seeing that we can save our template files as `.svg` rather than `.html` now I figured I could make svg components that could be used as follows.

`main.component.svg`

```
<svg>
    <my-svg-component></my-svg-component>
</svg>
```

`mySvg.component.svg`

```
<text x="0" y="60">test text</text>
```

I got an error saying `<text></text>` wasn't a recognized element so I modified it to this

```
<svg:text x="0" y="65">test text</svg:text>
```

The error went away however nothing is rendering.  I added the script directly into the `<svg>` tag in the `main.component.svg` file without the `svg:` at the beginning and it worked fine.

Is there something I should be doing in the `mySvg.component` template to make this work as a reusable component or do we have to generate all the SVG inside one template?

**UPDATE**

I tried using SVG's `<foreignObject>` like so

```
<svg>
    <foreignObject>
        <my-svg-component></my-svg-component>
    </foreignObject>
<svg>
```

this didn't work either.  I tested it out with a paragraph tag and noticed I had to use `<xhtml:p>` in order for it to render.  I tried adding the `xhmtl:` part to my component for grins and giggles and still didn't see anything render.  Now I'm wondering if there's an `angular:` of some form that can be used.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do that this way:

template:

```
<svg>
  <g svgtext></g>
</svg>
```

svg component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[svgtext]',
  template: `<svg:text x="0" y="65">test text</svg:text>`,
  styles: [`your styles come here`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

}
```

So the trick is to attach your svg component to another svg element (group - g) via **attribute selector**. This way resulting template is valid SVG and you can get your text rendered.

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fd1tcd

If you do component selector with tags, than SVG schmema is broken and browser won't be able to render SVG. Using group (which is a valid svg container) we avoid that issue and the additional component html gets injected right inside such a group.

You can read this fantastic article by Tero (pretty old now) for more insights:
https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html

Comment: splendid, thank you for sharing this, I knew there had to be a way to do it lol.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, you saved me .

Comment: This post talk about this too: https://programming.for-humans.io/posts/2020/angular-svg/working-with-angular-and-svg-component-relationships