# Angular 12 doesn't render svg component

Tags: angular, svg, angular-components

I am developing an angular component. it is an avatar creater using with svg. My problem is that when I run my component in angular project it draws just a circle not other components like nose,hair,face etc. ,but when I inspect my component and copy its svg elements and paste in a svg viewer, it shows as how should it be.

My Component in local
[image]

As you can see, my component has svg elements but doesn't rendered in browser. But,when I use same svg elements in a viewer they are rendered.

My Component's svg elements in online svg viewer
[image]

Also, here is project's [repo](https://github.com/bariscanyilmaz/ngx-nice-avatar)

Angular project version

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that, when I create components with selector tags , angular adds its own element tags to svg schema and this breasks the svg's schema and browser doesn't render it. So, I used attribute selector for achieving this problem. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58944913/8784762) answer help me to solve this problem.

Example project is [here](https://github.com/bariscanyilmaz/ngx-nice-avatar). You can check components under projects folder

I used attribute tag which is wrapped with `[`and `]` instead of selector tags.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[ngx-beard]',
  template: `
    <svg:g>
    <ng-container *ngIf="beard == 'Hipster'">
      <path
        d="M270.126 194.455C279.615 234.059 255.201 273.857 215.597 283.345C192.29 288.93 168.916 282.772 151.692 268.687C134.5 252.801 130.5 201.301 126.692 176.95C140.692 208.451 176.316 210.895 210.192 204.951C238.692 199.951 261.491 198.951 261.491 159.951C263.376 162.567 268.469 187.538 270.126 194.455Z"
        [attr.fill]="beardColor"
      />
    </ng-container>
   </g>
   `
  })
```

Comment: Please show how you solved it.

Comment: I said, I used attribute selector. I added project's source code you can check components under projects folder.

Comment: You should post the code for it as part of your code, so the answer is still helpful if the links one day dies.

Comment: @Jeppe I shared the code

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is due to the changedetection of angular.
Have you perhaps tried https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef
detectChanges after you change some other component?

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.random();
     this.cd.detectChanges()
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. problem not detecting changes, problem is nothing rendering in screen except that circle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was cause due to a mismatch of angulars syntax to set html attributes.
Beware of the defferent usage of

```
[style.height]="getHeight()"
...
getHeight(): string
```

and

```
[attr.height]="getHeight()"
...
getHeight(): string | number
```

Both work, but when you use [style.height], the method "getHeight()" **has to return a string value including "px" oder "em" or whatever**.

When using [attr.height] the method "getHeight()" **can return a number which is interpreted as a "px" value**.